# Hide passwords java commandline starup

Tags: java

Currently we pass the `password` like shown below but how to I make sure that it is hidden when a `ps` command is run

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keystoreLocation=${CERTLOCATION} -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=${PASSWORD}
```

One option that I saw online was to pass them as env variables. How can I do it?

Comment: You can get environment variables with `System.getenv()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String- . Set them in your shell beforehand e.g. `export KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=user3310115password`

Comment: @byxor the bigger problem is how to get that value to where it's supposed to go (to that `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` vm param) before it's used for the first time.